# entity_form removes uid

Tags: 7, entities

So i have defined a block

```
case 'foo_post':
    global $user;
    $values = array(
        'type' => 'foo',
        'uid' => $user->uid,
        'status' => 1,
        'comment' => 0,
        'promote' => 0
    );
    $entity = entity_create('node', $values);

    $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
    $ewrapper->og_group_ref->set(menu_get_object()->nid);

    $block['subject'] = t('Create a new foo');
    $block['content'] = entity_form('node', $entity, 'add');
    $block['content']['#attributes']['class'][] = drupal_html_class('panel-body');
    $block['content']['title']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $block['content']['form_title'] = ['#markup' => sprintf('<h4>%s</h4>', $block['subject']), '#weight' => -1];
    $block['content']['form_advanced'] = [
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => TRUE,
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Advanced settings'),
        'additional_settings' => $block['content']['additional_settings'],
        'og_group_ref' => $block['content']['og_group_ref']
    ];
    unset($block['content']['og_group_ref']);
    unset($block['content']['additional_settings']);
    break;
```

Most of the things work already, except the form wouldn't take the user ID of the user submitting the form. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The $user variable may not be set in this context - it is not automatically available as a local variable.

Try adding `global $user;` before the code.

Comment: i forgot that line in the question, it is there in the function, and i can confirm the value is correct, but still no, uid is still not saved

Comment: I gave up and use entityreference prepopulate + form block for this already anyway, thanks for the help regardless